# Best way to get the last non-empty worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) macro for a group tha

- has one workbook where they daily create new worksheets, and also have
- *Sheet 1*, *Sheet 2* and *Sheet 3* at the end of their long list of sheets.

I need to create a external cell reference in a new column in a different workbook where this information is being summarized.

So I need to know how to get the **last non-empty sheet** so I can grab this data and place it appropriately in the summary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function works through the sheets from right to left until it finds a non-blank sheet, and returns its name

```
Function GetLastNonEmptySheetName() As String
Dim i As Long
For i = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
  If Sheets(i).UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    GetLastNonEmptySheetName = Sheets(i).Name
    Exit Function
  End If
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been diving into excel VBA and learning fast I think but its different from the languages I know.

Answer (score 1):

The method above will ignore a sheet with a single cell entry, while that may seem to be a quibble, a `Find` looking for a non-blank cell will give more certainty.

The `xlFormulas` argument in the `Find` method will find hidden cells (but not filtered cells) whereas `xlValues` won't.

```
Sub FindLastSht()
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strSht As String
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For lngCnt = .Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set rng1 = .Sheets(lngCnt).Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas)
            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                strSht = .Sheets(lngCnt).Name
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lngCnt
        If Len(strSht) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Last used sheet in " & .Name & " is " & strSht
        Else
            MsgBox "No data is contained in " & .Name
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```